# Comparsion between structs for a set

Tags: c++, set, c++14, smart-pointers

This code works but having a struct called `ptrcomp` outside the `weighted_pointer` seems (to me) that they are different things.  I tried some different ways and even googled it, but I haven't found anything that works like this.

```
struct node{
    unsigned int oper;
    void * a;
    void * b;
};

struct weighted_pointer{
    mutable int weight;
    unique_ptr<node> pointer;
};

struct ptrcomp{
    bool operator()(const weighted_pointer & lhs, const weighted_pointer & rhs) {
        return tie(lhs.pointer->oper, lhs.pointer->a, lhs.pointer->b) < tie(rhs.pointer->oper, rhs.pointer->a, rhs.pointer->b);
    }
};

set<weighted_pointer,ptrcomp> gate;
```

My objective is to make the `std::set` working. And possibly write it like `set<weighted_pointer>`.

Comment: What errors are you seeing? How would you expect `set` to order these objects?

Comment: @sfjac There're no errors in this code. And it orders in the right way. But i don't want to have the `ptrcomp` struct. I'd like to know if it's possible to do it in another way to avoid to create another struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your code to

```
struct weighted_pointer {
    mutable int weight;
    unique_ptr<node> pointer;

    bool operator < (const weighted_pointer & rhs) const;
};

bool weighted_pointer::operator < (const weighted_pointer & rhs) const {
    return tie(pointer->oper, pointer->a, pointer->b) < tie(rhs.pointer->oper, rhs.pointer->a, rhs.pointer->b);
}
```

then it will work and you won't need a comparator `ptrcomp` for the `set` and can use the type `set<weighted_pointer>` as you wished. (You can also move the definition into the struct if you wish.)

Comment: Thank you, that's what i wanted. (With the definition into the struct). In this way is clear what the operator is it working with. I write it several times but was not working and now i see i was missing the const after the parameters. Could you explain me what is it for?

Comment: `const` after a method declaration tells the compiler that you won't modify any member data of an instance of that class/struct. If you do, or something you call does, it's an error and stops compilation. This is useful to prevent accidental modification of data when you know you just want to *use* it and not change it.

Comment: Useful! But how do I know (like in this case) when the std requires it? Is there in any reference written?

Comment: Well, for cases like this with comparison operators, I hadn't ever really thought of it; it's so automatic to me now (and it's good practice to add `const`, it's easy to change if you realize later that you really do want to modify object with an operation). That being said, removing `const` (in both the in-struct definition and declaration outside) doesn't keep it from compiling for me in VS2015. Is it failing if you actually insert data?

Comment: It's compiles alone. But when i used it: `gate.insert(move(weighted_pointer{1,make_unique<node>(*move_pointer)}));`. It gives me an error.

Comment: @UmurilLyerood If you define `move_pointer` with `node * move_pointer = new node{ 1, new int, new int };` then your code compiles. As far as reference material to why `const` is required, the best is the standard itself in **25.4 Sorting and related operations [alg.sorting]**. I know that's more than most people want to dig through, though, so I guess just know that set builds a tree (not required, but all implementations do this) and if `operator <` or a comparator modified the keys in any way it could invalidate the ordering of the tree and make any operations on it fail miserably.

Answer (score 4):

> having a struct called ptrcomp outside the weighted_pointer seems (to me) that they are different things.

That's how things really are. `weighted_pointer` is data, while `ptrcomp` is a way to compare the data. So, these two *really are* different things, and there is nothing wrong with your code.

If it happens that you have one canonical way of comparing your data, make it into `operator <`:

```
bool operator < (const weighted_pointer & lhs, const weighted_pointer & rhs) {
    return tie(lhs.pointer->oper, lhs.pointer->a, lhs.pointer->b) < tie(rhs.pointer->oper, rhs.pointer->a, rhs.pointer->b);
}
```

`std::set` will happily use it, if you use it as `std::set<weighted_pointer>` (in fact, `std::set` has the second template parameter defaulted to `std::less<T>`, which is a comparator class that uses `operator <`).

Comment: Where I should add this code? inside the `weighted_pointer` struct?

Comment: @UmurilLyerood in my version it is just a free function - place it wherever you want (don't forget `inline` keyword if you put the implementation in some header). Differently, you can make it a method of `weighted_pointer`, as @R2-Dequeue answer shows.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct weighted_pointer {
 // ...
 struct compare {
  // ...
  };
};


set<weighted_pointer,weighted_pointer::compare> gate;

// better

using weighted_pointer_set = set<weighted_pointer,weighted_pointer::compare>;
weighted_pointer_set gate;
```

This is how I see this usually done.

Having a `std::set<weighted_pointer>` means that the set uses `std::less` to compare the elements. This in turn calls `operator<` on the respective type, so if you provide an implementation of that operator it'll work.